# Roots of polynomials that are the product of 2 polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Given $p, q  \in \mathbb{F}[X]$, $deg(p) \land deg(q) \geq 1$ with no roots in $\mathbb{F}$. How could we show that $p.q$ has no roots as well?
Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: What does $\mathbb{K}$ denote here?

Comment: Also, does $*$ denote convolution (as in mathematics) or multiplication (as in many computer languages)?

Comment: I meant normal multiplication and $\mathbb{K}$ was supposed the be some arbitrary field which is denoted like that in german but I should have written $\mathbb{F}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic words are "division with remainder". If $a$ is a root of the product, then $(x-a)$ divides $p q,$ but we know that $x-a$ does not divide either $p$ or $q.$ So $p = s (x-a) + r_1, q = t (x-a) + r_2,$ $pq = (x-a) v +. r_1 r_2.$ $r_1 r_2 \neq 0$ (since $\mathbb{K}$ is a field and has no zero divisors.)

Comment: If $\mathbb{K}$ is a field, or more generally an integral domain, isn't it simpler to say that $a\in\mathbb{K}$ root of $pq \iff p(a)q(a)=0 \iff p(a)=0 \text{ or } p(b)=0$ (as $\mathbb{K}$ is an integral domain), hence $a$ is a root of either $p$ or $q$? It also works in general for functions $p, q: \mathbb{K}\to \mathbb{K}$ with no roots.

Comment: @user6725906 Yes, it is simpler to say, but one might argue that it is logically equivalent :)

Answer (score 1):

$p, q  \in \mathbb{K}[X] \land \forall a \in \mathbb{K}:p,q \neq 0 \implies pq \neq 0$ because $ \mathbb{K} $ is a field and thus has no  zero divisors (a product of nonzero elements can only be zero if at least one of them is zero).